# How to make one of multiple async functions wait some specific one or make run as synchronously for some specific cases?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, rxjs

In an Angular application I have the below component and service. I have three checkboxes in related divs and normally default checkbox is selected against the data got from the async api call in `ngOnInit`.

I have needed to remove default checkbox if it is not bought as a part of a feature and when this happens and that checkbox is removed from template with `ngIf`, I need to select next one as default.

My feature check service method is an `async` method so I have called it like `(async () => { ... })()` as shown in the below.

I have tested and it sometimes marks the next one, but sometimes not. So I think that since my new method call is also async, their order is unknown.

I use the async getFeatures method from several places via a custom structural directive to decide whether render templates or not for most of the cases that have no precondition, so I had not a requirement like this, but in this case I have a condition so I have a order between async calls.

My questions are,

1. How can I call `async getFeatures() {}` synchronously in this case?
2. How can I setup as getFeatures will run last or after `getPreset`?

```js
@Component({
/...
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit() {

     //do some things 

     this.getPreset(); //async calls 
     
     // my new async function call
     (async () => {
      let utpFeature = await this.featureService.getFeatures("runPlans");
      this.utpFeatureStatus = utpFeature ? utpFeature.Status : true;

      //enabling next one which is "FillInYourself" checkbox if it does not have a feature
      this.MyForm.controls["FillInYourself"].setValue(!this.utpFeatureStatus);
       
    })();
   }

   getPreset() {
      //get a lot of data async from multiple services 

      //set one of three checkboxes as marked as default.
      forkJoin([getFoo, getBar, getBaz]).subscribe((results: any) => {
         //transform result and process data
         checkedUseFirstPlan(data); //normally default checkbox
      }
   }

   checkedUseFirstPlan(data: boolean) {
    if (!data) {
      this.MyForm.controls["UseFirstPlan"].setValue(true);
      return;
    }
    this.MyForm.controls["UseFirstPlan"].setValue(data);
    this.MyForm.controls["FillInYourself"].setValue(!data);
    this.MyForm.controls["OtherPlan"].setValue(!data);
  }
}



//service
async getFeatures(keyname: string) {
   //...
   await this.apiService.getFeatures().toPromise().then((result: any) => {
      //process result and obtain feature related to this keyname
   }
   return feature;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of doing async functions with help of `await`. All 3 functions in example will run one after another in strict order

```js
// Use async
(async () => {
  // Function 1
  const fn1 = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Do some stuff here
      val = val + 1;
      // Resolve result.
      // Can be resolved from any level
      // of nested function!
      function nested1() {
        function nested2() {
          resolve(val);
        }
        nested2();
      }
      nested1();
    });
  };
  
  // Function 2
  const fn2 = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Do some stuff here
      val = val * 2;
      // Resolve result
      resolve(val);
    });
  };
  
  // Function 3
  const fn3 = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Do some stuff here
      val = val + 1000;
      // Resolve result
      resolve(val);
    });
  };
  
  // Sync code
  let val = 5;
  
  val = await fn1(val); // Wait until fn1 resolves
  val = await fn2(val); // Wait until fn2 resolves
  val = await fn3(val); // Wait until fn3 resolves
  
  console.log(val);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you @tarkh, Does it mean that `fn2` will **always** wait for `fn1` to finish or will start same time when you call with `await fn1(val)` and then `await fn2(val)`? I'm also aware that you pass the result of first async call `val = await fn1(val);` to `fn2(val)`, is this the reason that makes them sync?

Comment: Yes, `await` will pause current scope execution (parent `async` function, in which you do `await`...), so fn2 will start only after you do `resolve` fn1 function. And last normal function - `console.log` will execute only after fn3 will be resolved. So this way you can create linear code in JavaScript

Comment: And no, parameters which and how you pass to function does not influence the way how `await` works, in my case it's just an example that you can alter value in async functions in linear manner - without callbacks and nested functions.

Comment: Thanks @tarkh, one last question, in the context of my code I understand that I need to change `getPreset()` to return a promise and await that promise in the `(async () => { await getPreset(); let utpFeature = await this.featureService.getFeatures("runPlans");...})()` is that right? I think `Observable` has a method as `toPromise()`, maybe I should use it instead of `subscribe of forkjoin`, but I will try, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Cant say about angular, haven't work with it... But in general in JS keep in mind, that `await` works only in `async` function and only within them. Everything outside `async` function will run kind of parallel. So design your software in the way you need... You can, i.e., return `promise` from `async` function itself to it's parent, and wait for it to complete there and so on